# ros_canopen did not receive a response message

Tags: ros, ros-control, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I trying to use ros_canopen to control a robot with canopen motors. I use indigo.

I run candump in a terminal. When I connect the motor to power,candump receives:

```
~/ws $ rosrun socketcan_interface socketcan_dump can0
ERROR: state=1 internal_error=0('OK') asio: system:0
ERROR: state=2 internal_error=0('OK') asio: system:0
s 702   1 0
s 82    8 30 81 0 0 0 40 0 0
```

So I suppose the hardware connection is correct.

However when I load parameters and then run canopen_motor_node , it gave an error:

```
$ rosrun canopen_motor_node canopen_motor_node 

[ WARN] [1462871551.731234857]: Sync overflow was not specified, so overflow is disabled per default

Did not receive a response message

[ERROR] [1462871553.457722242]: 
/home/craig/ws/src/ros_canopen/canopen_master/include/canopen_master/objdict.h(457): Throw in function canopen::ObjectStorage::Entry<T> canopen::ObjectStorage::entry(const canopen::ObjectDict::Key&) [with T = signed char]
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::bad_cast> >
std::exception::what: std::bad_cast
```

The configuration of CAN bus is simple and is [Here](https://github.com/Birl-K/BIRL-Modubot/tree/master/src/modular_robot_control/config).The eds is provided by Copley.

I've tried to read the code where produces the "Did not receive a response message" but could find out how to solve this problem.

Any help will be appreciated .Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234019/ros_canopen-did-not-receive-a-response-message/) by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2016-05-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-10**:
If at all possible, please don't use screenshots of terminal output. It's all text, and can easily be copy/pasted into the question. Images aren't searchable, and if the screenshots ever disappear, this question will be worthless.

If you decide to update, please *edit* your original question.

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-05-10**:
Thx for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The branch of ros_canopen i use is indigo-devel,which i found out very different from indigo_release_candidate.Which one is more recommended?

indigo-devel is the most recent and recommended version.

> 82 8 30 81 0 0 0 40 0 0

This is a heatbeat failure. (You're controller waits for a heartbeat message, but you have not configured to send it?)

> boost::exception_detail::clone_implboost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::bad_cast > std::exception::what: std::bad_cast

The driver expects another data type (signed char), I guess you're EDS states something else.

It is really hard to debug if you don't provide your config.
I guess you have been calling the init service from another shell?

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-05-10**:
I have checked your EDS with CANchkEDS, it does not match the standard object types.
You should install CANeds (v3.6 works with wine) and resolve all errors.

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-05-10**:
Thanks! I will try it. I download this EDS file from [Copley website](http://www.copleycontrols.com/Motion/Downloads/firmware.html). Strange problem that it should not match the standard object types. Do you think this leads to problems that I mentioned above?Thanks.

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-05-17**:
i have checked the eds file with CANeds. After I fixed two errors that CANeds gave, I still got the bad_cast. There are some warnings about not clearifying remapping direction of some object. Copley replied that other costumers did well with this eds . And it still "did not receive response msg"

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-05-19**:
Please update your EDS on github.
A faulty EDS might work for others, but `ros_canopen` relies on the type information because of its strict type policy.

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-05-19**:
Updated eds file is [here](https://github.com/Birl-K/modular_robot/blob/master/config/CopleyAmp2.eds). The main difference from its original file is the "EDSVersion=3.0" is changed to "EDSVersion=4.0" and a sub-index data type is modified to conform to it's parent index.

**Comment by [Craig](https://answers.ros.org/users/26391/craig/) on 2016-05-19**:
Besides, AccessType in the eds file is changed into lowercase. (canopen_motor_node doesn't accept uppercase ones)
E.g. "AccessType=RW"  -->  "AccessType=rw"
CANeds gave warnings about not specifying the mapping direction.I think AccessType of mappable object with rw access should change to rwr or rw

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2016-05-30**:
Your EDS still uses wrong types for a number of objects. In CANeds you have to add the 402 database (Ctrl+F2).